# How do I test that an std::error_code is not an error?

Tags: c++

I have a method that returns an `std::error_code`. I am not particularly interested in the error message, only in whether or not the method succeeded.

What is the best way to test that an `std::error_code` represents a successful operation?

Comment: Have you tried std::error_code::operator bool()? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code/operator_bool

Comment: Does `true` indicate succcess or failure?

Comment: "Return false if value() == 0, true otherwise." As of what a value == zero means: "std::error_code is a platform-dependent error code"

Comment: So there is no way to test if an error_code represents success in a platform-independent way?

Comment: I can't find the official reference, but I would assume that an error_code::value() == 0 means success. An unofficial ref (but old, for c++0x) can be found here: http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-2.html

Comment: At the end of the day only "the other programmer" who implemented that method really knows. I'd think it would be customary to return 0 for "no error".

Comment: Like they couldn't make `operator bool()` virtual to actually do something useful. I like how standard library pretends that virtual function in C++ do not exist or that they're evil...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I came across the similar situation when working with the ASIO library. As what [one of their blog posts](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-2.html) suggests, `std::error_code` is meant to be tested as follows:

```
std::error_code ec;
// ...    
if (!ec)
{
  // Success.
}
else
{
  // Failure.
}
```

Having dug a little deeper, I found [this](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/b3gMahfDxSw) (much more recent) discussion in the C++ Standard Google group, which confirms the statement above but also raises questions about whether the current design of `std::error_code` is straightforward enough.

Long story short, if you need to simply tell errors from success, `!static_cast<bool>(errorCode)` is what you need.

Comment: Thanks. Definitely not straightforward to me. The trend of sacrifice usability for engineering purity is going on.